# twitter bootstrap tooltip with images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using twitter bootstrap to add tooltips.

Heres my JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a img").tooltip({'placement': 'right'});
});
</script>
```

I am trying to append an image with jquery with the rel attr for tooltips like this:

```
$(".info").append('<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip"><img src="http://extrarewards.nationalexpress.com/images/assets/info_icon.png"/></a>');});
```

Without the image this works, but as soon as i add the image in it stops working.

Any ideas what is wrong with the above?

Comment: show us your html code also

Comment: this is php so html is generated dynamically

Comment: so show us php code that creates `img`

Comment: its just a database query to pull in the image src....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax on your `.append` is off. Try:

```
$(".info").append('<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip"><img src="http://extrarewards.nationalexpress.com/images/assets/info_icon.png"></a>');
```

Demo: **[Bootply.com/65857](http://bootply.com/65857)**

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seem to be you have solved your problem. But I would like to give a different solution for your problem. I personally use this method to add tooltip texts to images.

Here is my **HTML** part.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Your tool tip text here."><img src="imgs/sample.png"></a>
```

Now here is the **Jquery** part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

If you want to know more about bootstrap tooltips you could refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Best way in my view

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="<img src='../../images/mrraja.jpg' width='105' height='130' />">1</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
animated: 'fade',
placement: 'bottom',
html: true
}); 
});
</script>
```